# Can't find java.util.stream in java8

Tags: intellij-idea, java

I have installed `jdk-8-ea-bin-b82-windows-x64-21_mar_2013` and **IntelliJ IDEA 12.0.4**. The strange thing is that I can't find `java.util.stream` in the intellisense provided by the IDE. I tried to compile either using the IDE or using the notepad and the compiler but it gives an error complaining that `java.util.stream` cannot be found! I have already set the module settings to use Java8 jdk. Any ideas about this problem?

Comment: Have you tried to find other Java 8 specific APIs?

Comment: Yes, I have looked for java.util.function and found it!

Comment: Well perhaps the java.util.stream package / classes are not part of that snapshot.

Comment: I have downloaded the latest release as indicated above. Or else what release should I use?

Comment: What I'm saying is that maybe the java.util.stream package / classes are not available yet.  After all, it is an early access release ... not even a beta yet.

Comment: As of 1.8.0-ea-b92 package java.util.stream is available!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @rmuller pointed out there was no streams in the early release version that I have downloaded 5 years ago when I asked the question. Short while after I asked the question a new release was available and it contained the streams support.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with Netbeans. It seams that older versions of JDK 8 are not correctly packaged.

I had the same problem with b84, but I installed the build b116 and it is working properly.

PS: I think this is what @rmuller said in his comment

Answer (score 2):

To change the JDK version, go to File --> Project Structure, and make sure both Project SDK and Project Language Level are set to JDK 8.

*(I know you said you set the JDK level in the modules already, but I'm posting this here because there is relatively little information online on how to do that.  Even the [IDEA documentation](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under) on this issue doesn't mention it!)*

Answer (score 0):

Try to download from: http://jdk8.java.net/lambda/ to have lambda and stream support

Comment: Check in $JDK_HOME/jre/lib/rt.jar for package 'java.util.stream' where JDK_HOME should point to your JDK8 of course. also check IDEA settings : http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-global-project-and-module-sdks.html

Comment: No java.util.stream does not exist in rt.jar in either of the JDKs I have downloaded.

Comment: You downloaded: lambda-8-bxx-linux-x64-xx_xxx_2013.tar.gz? and there is no java.util.stream?

Comment: Not the linux version but the windows version.

Comment: I am having the same problem here. Exploded the zip:

    $ find . -name "stream"
    ./com/sun/imageio/stream
    ./javax/xml/stream
    ./javax/xml/transform/stream
    ./javax/imageio/stream
    ./java/util/stream

Comment: Re-imported project, but IDEA is still complaining.

Answer (score -1):

YOU CAN SET PROJECT SETTING IN MODULES

THE LANGUAGE LEVEL SET 8-LAMBDAS
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8riM.png)

BEACUSE THE DEFAULT LANGUAGE LEVEL IS 7 -Diamonds

Comment: Ah, you don't have to yell.

Comment: The question was asked while Java 8 was in the early release stage. The problem has been solved long ago but I did not mark an answer since the solution was provided by a comment from rmuller so I just upvoted him.