# How to download java.util.stream.Collectors.jar

Tags: java, jar, download

I would appreciate a lot if someone can point me a link to download java.util.stream.Collectors.jar.

Thanks

Comment: Just by form specifically off-topic, but the class in question is a part of the JRE.

Comment: @chrylis I am sorry for my ignorance. I have installed JRE1.8 but still my java class gives an error saying it cannot find package java.util.stream

Comment: Then you've configured something else wrong.  It's not in a separate jar.

Comment: Then you're still compiling with an older JDK.

Comment: @chrylis thanks a lot. My netbeans was pointing to JDK 1.7. The problem solved when I pointed back to 1.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this , there seems to be a problem with the java version downloaded.

[Can't find java.util.stream in java8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15706048/cant-find-java-util-stream-in-java8)

Comment: thanks a lot. My netbeans was pointing to JDK 1.7. The problem solved when I pointed back to 1.8

Comment: Great, Whenever you have an issue with a jar that comes along with the JDK , always check your configuration.